# C#: Protected method in base class; unable to access using derived class object from another class

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, access-modifiers

Should protected members of a base class be accessible to a class which inherits from base class?

I'm trying to access protected method of base class using an object of derived class from another class, but I get this error message

```
the base class method is inaccessible due to protection level
```

What am I doing wrong?

Program.cs

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DerivedClass dc = new DerivedClass();
        dc.DisplayValue();

    }
}
```

BaseClass.cs

```
class BaseClass
{
    private int value = 3;

    protected void DisplayValue()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this.value);
    }
}
```

DerivedClass.cs

```
class DerivedClass : BaseClass{}
```

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/keywords/protected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code within DerivedClass has access to protected members of BaseClass, but only via an expression of type DerivedClass or a subtype.

Your Main function is outside the Derived Class and that's why you are getting exception.

From section 3.5.3 of the C# 5 specification (emphasis mine):

> When a **protected** instance member is accessed outside the program text
>   of the class in which it is declared, and when a **protected internal**
>   instance member is accessed outside the program text of the program in
>   which it is declared, the access **must** take place within a class
>   declaration that derives from the class in which it is declared.
>   Furthermore, the access is required to take place through an instance
>   of that derived class type or a class type constructed from it.

You can change you code to this for example to use protected function of the base class

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DerivedClass dc = new DerivedClass();
            dc.Display();
        }
    }
    public class BaseClass
    {
        private int value = 3;

        protected void DisplayValue()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(this.value);
        }
    }
    public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
    {
        public void Display()
        {
            DisplayValue();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Protected members are indeed visible from derived classes. But in your example you don't access `DisplayValue` from a derived class. You access it from `Program`, which does *not* derive from `BaseClass`. You need to make that member `public`.